Debugging on remote machine CMake project using Visual Studio 2019 launch.vs.json
I'm trying to debug my binary (crosscompiled C++ with VS CMake project) on remote host (Unix-like) with launch.vs.json.

I've created CMake project in Visual Studio 2019 (Version 16.11.42).

Using crosscompilation I've built my Unix executable. It builds on my Windows host and runs fine on remote host. I could run it on its own, I could debug it with gdb on remote host.

Using menu "Debug->Debug and Launch settings for MyProgram" I've created 'launch.vs.json' with defaults like this:


{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "src\\CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProgram",
      "name": "MyProgram"
    }
  ]
}


I've modified 'launch.vs.json' default configuration to use gdb on remote host with custom ssh connection like this:

{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "name": "remote gdb debug MyProgram",
      "project": "src\\CMakeLists.txt",
      "projectTarget": "MyProgram", // should be same as target name in 'Select Startup Item' dropdown menu
      "targetArchitecture": "x86",
      "currentDir": "/home/",
      "debuggerConfiguration": "gdb",
      "program": "/home/MyProgram",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "pipeTransportOptions": true,
      "pipeTransport": {
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/host/x86/usr/bin/gdb",
        "pipeProgram": "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink",
        "pipeArgs": [
          "root@192.168.56.223",
          "-pw",
          "12345"
        ],
        "pipeCwd": "C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY"
      },
      "customLaunchSetupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Turn off autoformat for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


When trying to launch 'MyProgram' as Startup Item (green arrow button with combobox on top in VS interface) I'm getting meaningless error 'Unable to start debugging. The startup project could not be launched.'

Seems like Visual Studio didn't even look in my 'launch.vs.json' configuration and at this point after examining documentation and web (f.e. 1, 2, 3, some examples in github issues) I'm stuck. I have tried to change 'name', 'projectTarget', 'project', 'program' with different combinations but nothing works.
What's wrong with config? Maybe there are some logs of Visual Studio I could turn on and examine?
P.S. If I add in CMakeSettings.json another configuration for host platform (Windows) and switch to it then my crossplatform application 'MyProgram.exe' runs just fine.
P.P.S. Configuration is taken straight from actually working VSCode 'launch.json' with minimal changes in field names.
